# Deploy python app with setup.py and Pipfile

Tags: python, setuptools, pipenv

I have a flask app with a Pipfile and run `pipenv run python setup.py sdist` to create a package. I copy the package to another system.

Usually I would install it with pip and all requirements declared in install_requires in setup.py would be installed automatically.

How can I install the package and its requirements and make use of the Pipfile.lock?

If I install the package with pip, I could run `pipenv install --deploy` in the directory it was installed, but how can I reliably retrieve the directory my package was installed in? Is this a good way to do this?

I'm looking for the best way to install a python app with setuptools and pipenv.

Comment: Hi Kris, did you find a solution?

Comment: I'll post my thoughts on this in the next few days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll share my thoughts on this.

First, the abstract dependencies of your project are to be listed in setup.py's install_requires. They should not be pinned if possible and reading dependencies in setup.py from somewhere else is not recommended.

Thus, if you install a package created with `python setup.py sdist`, that project's Pipfile.lock will not be used. Instead the user of the package is reponsible for locking the dependencies and installing the package into a virtualenv.

To use our Pipfile.lock we need a different approach to deployment. I've collected a few.

1) `git clone` the repository on target machine or `rsync -r` it to target machine. Run `pipenv install --deploy` in cloned project directory. There are several ways of using the virtualenv:

- Launch the app with `pipenv run <appname>` from the cloned project directory. Make sure you are the same user who created the virtualenv.
- Retrieve the virtualenv location by running `pipenv --venv` from the cloned project directory as the same user who created the virtualenv and use it directly for running your app.
- Set `PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1` environment variable before running `pipenv install --deploy` to get a consistent virtualenv location that you can then use directly for running your app.
- Before running pipenv, manually create a virtualenv then run pipenv from there. Pipenv will automatically use that virtualenv instead of creating a new one. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49388414/7662112 for a complete workflow.

2) Use `pipenv install --system --deploy` to set up the virtualenv from your Pipfile.lock in docker. Then just use the docker image for deployment.

3) Dump Pipfile.lock into a requirements.txt with `pipenv lock --requirements > requirements.txt` and build a deb package using `dh-virtualenv`.