# pipenv: deployment workflow

Tags: python, pipenv

I am thinking about switching from pip & virtualenv to pipenv.  But after studying the documentation I am still at a loss on how the creators of pipenv structured the deployment workflow.

For example, in development I have a `Pipfile` & a `Pipfile.lock` that define the environment.  Using a deployment script I want to deploy

1. `git pull` via Github to production server
2. `pipenv install` creates/refreshes the environment in the home directory of the deployment user

But I need a venv in a **specific** directory which is already configured in systemd or supervisor.  E.g.: `command=/home/ubuntu/production/application_xy/env/bin/gunicorn module:app`

pipenv creates the env in some location such as 
`/home/ultimo/.local/share/virtualenvs/application_xy-jvrv1OSi`

**What is the intended workflow to deploy an application with `pipenv`?**

Comment: in case you solved this issue, would you mind refferencing a list of commands for the workflow? i have this cheatsheet would be amazing if you could commit to it https://github.com/elfelround/ec2-deployment-cheatsheet/blob/master/2.7%20remastered%20for%203%20with%20pipenv

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have few options there.

1. You can run your gunicorn via `pipenv run`:

   `pipenv run gunicorn module:app`

This creates a slight overhead, but has the advantage of also loading environment from `$PROJECT_DIR/.env` (or other `$PIPENV_DOTENV_LOCATION`).

2. You can set the `PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT` environment variable. This will keep pipenv's virtualenv in `$PROJECT_DIR/.venv` instead of the global location.
3. You can use an existing virtualenv and run pipenv from it. Pipenv will not attempt to create its own virtualenv if it's run from one.
4. You can just use the weird pipenv-created virtualenv path.

Comment: may i ask how you solved this issue in production? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54378879/pipenv-on-production-workaround-with-user-is-it-viable

Answer (score 12):

I've just switched to `pipenv` for deployment and my workflow is roughly as follows (managed with [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/)). For an imaginary project called "project", assuming that a working Pipfile.lock is checked into source control:

1. Clone the git repository:

   `git clone https://github.com/namespace/project.git /opt/project`
2. Change into that directory

   `cd /opt/project`
3. Check out the target reference (branch, tag, ...):

   `git checkout $git_ref`
4. Create a virtualenv somewhere, with the target Python version (3.6, 2.7, etc):

   `virtualenv -p"python$pyver" /usr/local/project/$git_ref`
5. Call pipenv in the context of that virtualenv, so it won't install its own:

   `VIRTUAL_ENV="/usr/local/project/$git_ref" pipenv --python="/usr/local/project/$git_ref/bin/python" install --deploy`

   The `--deploy` will throw an error, when the Pipfile.lock does not match the Pipfile.
6. Install the project itself using the virtualenv's `pip` (only necessary if it isn't already in the Pipfile):

   `/usr/local/project/$git_ref/bin/pip install /opt/project`
7. Set a symlink to the new installation directory:

   `ln -s /usr/local/project/$git_ref /usr/local/project/current`

My application is then callable e.g. with `/usr/local/project/current/bin/project_exec --foo --bar`, which is what's configured in [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/), for instance.

All of this is triggered when a tag is pushed to the remote.

As the virtualenvs of earlier versions remain intact, a rollback is simply done by setting the `current-`symlink back to an earlier version. I.e. if tag 1.5 is broken, and I want to go back to 1.4, all I have to do is `ln -s /usr/local/project/1.4 /usr/local/project/current` and restart the application with `supervisorctl`.

Comment: so i have been following the commands listed here but I am having the issue of pipenv making pip unusable which is also listed on the commands linked, however the answer i saw somewhere of installing pipenv under specific user alert me https://github.com/elfelround/ec2-deployment-cheatsheet/blob/master/2.7%20remastered%20for%203%20with%20pipenv

Comment: @Mr-Programs WDYM pipenv makes pip unusable? What does not work?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ok09j.png or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54378879/pipenv-on-production-workaround-with-user-is-it-viable

Comment: I see. This is not specific to pipenv though, but a general problem of using `sudo pip install ...` alongside your package manager to install python-packages. You should install `pipenv` for some specific user instead (with `pip install --user pipenv`)

Answer (score 8):

I think pipenv is very good for managing dependencies but is too slow, cumbersome and still a bit unstable for using it for automatic deployments.

Instead I use virtualenv (or virtualenvwrapper) and pip on the target machine.

- On my **build/development machine** I create a `requirements.txt` compatible text file using `pipenv lock -r`:

  ```
    $ pipenv lock -r > deploy-requirements.txt
  ```
- While deploying, inside a virtualenv I run:

  ```
    $ pip install -r deploy-requirements.txt
  ```

Comment: as oposed to a pip freeze?

Comment: @Mr-Programs `pipenv lock -r` as opposed to `pip freeze` gets you sha256 hashes for packages, which I prefer as my code is more reproducible. 

From [the docs](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics/#example-pipfile-pipfile-lock):

"Note
If you’d like a requirements.txt output of the lockfile, run $ pipenv lock -r. This will include all hashes, however (which is great!). To get a requirements.txt without hashes, use $ pipenv run pip freeze."

Answer (score 5):

Just do this:

```
mkdir .venv
pipenv install
```

Explanation:

`pipenv` checks your project directory for a sub directory named `.venv`. If it finds it, then **pipenv creates a local virtual environment** (because then it sets automatically `PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=true`)

So now if you want you can either activate the virtual environment with:

```
source .venv/bin/activate
```

Or config you app.conf for gunicorn with something like this:

```
exec /path/to/.venv/bin/gunicorn myapp:app
```

Answer (score 4):

To create virtual environment in the same directory as the project set the following environment variable <sup>[doc](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/#pipenv.environments.PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT)</sup>

```
PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=true
```

This installs the dependencies to `.venv` directory inside project. Available from PipEnv `v2.8.7`