# pipenv on production workaround with user, is it viable?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, pipenv

I have been experiencing [this issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51225750/installation-of-pipenv-causes-pip3-unusable) when I am trying to set pipenv on EC2.t2 free tier for production with Django.

On the solution listed on that same post it says:

> it is important to note that pipenv will likely not be able to be
>   installed at the global level due to the pip conflict. You can install
>   pipenv at the user level:
>
> > pip install --user pipenv

My question is, since this is production mode, wouldn't this be bringing me problems later on since I am installing my packages with some random user's privileges?

Anyone has any video of using pipenv in production?

Answer (score 1):

No, this usually should not cause any problems.

All you need to be taking care of is that the user that is to be running your installed application has permission to do so. I don't think that it matters much which user creates the virtualenv your application will ultimately reside in (which basically is what pipenv controls).